# How to display search list below of the search with the same width of the search by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a search list made off with `ul` in HTML that list will be displayed after you type in the search or after you click the button, actually both are working well the problem is when the search list is displayed by clicking the button, It doesn't display the list with the same width of my search, i tried things like this:

```js
$('#search-box-btn').click(function () { // on a click on botton
        //$('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
        $('#myUL').css({
            'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
        }).toggle();
})
```

But applying that doesn't look so good because you can note little differences when is displayed in that way, even made some mistakes changing the position when is displayed.

It should always look like this

[image]

But now looks like this

[image]

```css
#search-box{
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px ; 
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

.divider-border{
    border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input:focus ~ .btn-default {
    background: white ;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: white;
 }

 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background : url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png") ;
 }
  
  #myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: fit-content;
    max-height: 13rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /*margin-top: -0.5px; /*This hide the line between the input and the search list*/
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
  }
  
  #myUL li a {
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  }
  
  #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #737272; 
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Emails View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
           
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col-10" id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Searchbar -->
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <div class="input-group mt-4">
                            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                                <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu col-12" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">George</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Alis</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Alberto</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="searchFilter()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
                            <span class="divider-border"></span>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="search-box-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Searchbar -->
                
                  </div>
               




<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Test function for li-->
<!--<script>
                                        
    let selectUL = document.getElementById('myUL');
    let array = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.','Unde eos at non possimus culpa eius, doloremque, dolorem repudiandae ea illum porro,','sunt vel molestiae accusantium facilis. Necessitatibus nemo','bc','bf','ck','lp','th','et']
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        $('#myUL').append("<li><a href='#'>"+"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde eos at non possimus culpa eius, doloremque, dolorem repudiandae ea illum porro, sunt vel molestiae accusantium facilis."+item+i+"</a></li>");
    }

</script>-->
<script>
    function searchFilter() {
      // Declare variables
      let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('search-box');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<script>
    $('#search-box').on('input', function() {
        $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
    });
</script>

<script>
    let myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
    let search = document.getElementById('search-box');
    $('#search-box-btn').click(function () { // on a click on botton
        //$('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
        $('#myUL').css({
            //'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
        }).toggle();
    })

    $("li").on("click", function(){
        $("#search-box").val($(this).text());
        $('#myUL').hide();
        // myFunction(); You can put this here if you want to search right after a user clicked
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(".chart-section").on('click', function() {
        let pieChart = $(this);
        let table = $("#table");
        let chartBackground = pieChart.css('background-color');
        let chartText = pieChart.html();

        $("#square2").css('transform', 'translate(590px, -26px)');
        $("#square1").css('transform', 'translate(340px, -200px)');

        table.css('background-color', chartBackground).css('transform', 'translate(0px, -458px)').html('Participants Table' + '<br>' + chartText);
    });
</script>
    
<script>
  
    var contentBg = document.getElementById('content');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
    var square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    document.onclick = function(e){
        if(e.target.id == 'content'){
            table.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square1.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square2.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            ul.style.display = 'none';
        }
        
    }
  
</script>

<script>
    function light_input(){
        let search = document.getElementById('search-box');
        let button = document.getElementById('search-box-btn');
        button.style.background = 'white';
        search.style.background = 'white';
        search.style.boxShadow = 'inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a property transform applied on `#myUL` .

overwrite that property or remove it. It will start working.[image]

Comment: I remove it but still not looking good as you can see, now the list hides the input https://www.screencast.com/t/i5knmpF8P

Comment: Almost forgot, you have to mention the top, as you can see in the screenshot, I used certain top. Also, make it's parent div to be relative if it is not already